# Draw 10million per second points with variable intensity on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, android-canvas, android-view

Drawing on android itself, is a herculean task. Now my requirement is on to see, how robust I can draw atleast 10million points with different intensity levels.

Some methods I came across:

1. Android draws with Canvas and Bitmaps
2. SurfaceView with OpenGL
3. Using libGDX fastest drawing library
4. Custom view to refresh & update automatically

What is best method to go about it? If I need to draw 10million or more points maybe on a static image on android, how can I enhance it and not degrade its performance. Every second I need to refresh and draw another 10million points. Is it possible or android is capable of doing such a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As your question states 10mil/sec, I understand that you want them realtime, thus opengl is the way to go, leaving you with options 2, 3 and 4.
2. You would definitely need to batch those calls.
3. You can think about using point sprites to reduce the amount of data you need to transfer to GPU.
4. Android as OS is capable of anything your machine can support. Your specific device may have performance issues, or not.

Don't optimize prematurely and try option 3 (libGDX). It would be the easiest to set up and achieve your task. If it won't be performant enough I'd think about rolling my own opengl-based solution.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/opengl-es-2-0-point-sprites-size

Comment: But I'm not sure how to interface libGDX with any native code, where as Android provides a provision (NDK) for the same. I was wondering, to interface with native if any performance issues would be seen.

Comment: libGDX is pure java game/rendering engine. If you would require to use native code in attempt to get performance boost you have several options:

 1. roll your own opengl-es based rendering solution
 2. use some native engine, that supports android (Cocos2d-x is a good idea)

Comment: how do you do your own opengl-es based rendering solution using native layer? Any suggestions? I shall have a look at Cocos2d-x

Comment: If you wish to use NDK, you can take a look at the example code supplied with NDK. Specifically, take a look at YourNDKDirectory/samples/hello-gl2. Keep in mind, that for rolling your own solution you should have working knowledge of opengl es 2.0. If you would go with a pure native solution via NativeActivity you would also need to provide the rendering context manually, thus you'd need to research EGL.